# AttributeError: type object 'WordFamily' has no attribute 'words

Tags: python

when I call the check_type function, it would appear AttributeError: type object 'WordFamily' has no attribute 'words'

```
class WordFamily:
  def __init__(self, words, suffixes):
    self.words = words
    self.suffixes = suffixes
    
  def check_type(word):
    for w in WordFamily.words:
      if word in w or word + WordFamily.suffixes in w:
        return WordFamily.words
```

```
verb = ["love", "hate"]
WordFamily(verb,[""])
```

```
WordFamily.check_type("love")
```

What I expect is "verb"

what appear is
AttributeError: type object 'WordFamily' has no attribute 'words'
Error in this line: for w in WordFamily.words:

Comment: @Axe319
Oh sorry, 
the code WordFamily(verb,[" "])
should be added

Comment: Try to change WordFamily.words by self.words in all the ocurrences

Comment: @NachoR.
I have tried it, but this error message appeared:
NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: You also need `self` as the first parameter in instance methods like `check_type()`, so `def check_type(self, word)`.

Comment: Hi @MichaelRuth
thanks for the advice, when I added self as the first parameter, this error message appeared.

TypeError: check_type() missing 1 required positional argument: 'word'

Comment: This is because you're trying to access it as a class method rather than an instance method. Take a look at @CoryKramer's answer for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should refactor your class so `check_type` accepts `self` as the first argument and you can therefore reference instance variables. Otherwise `check_type` is trying to act like a `@class_method` but the values are not intended to act that way in your case.

```
class WordFamily:
  def __init__(self, words, suffixes):
    self.words = words
    self.suffixes = suffixes
    
  def check_type(self, word):
    for w in self.words:
      if word in w or word + self.suffixes in w:
        return self.words
```

Then you would use this like

```
verb = ["love", "hate"]
wf = WordFamily(verb,[""])
wf.check_type("love")
```

Comment: Hi Cory, thanks! 

it is working now

May I know is there any chance that it could return the name of the list which is "Verb" is this case but not returning the list elements?

Many thanks